# How to replace the base image url by an external image url setted by an attribute in Magento 1.9

Tags: image, magento, url, external

I have Magento 1.9 and I am using a remote server for the storage of images.

I created a new attribute (text field) for setting the external image url. I succeded to show the external image in the view and list/grid pages of the products but it is not efficient.

My question is :

Is there any solution to completely rewrite the base image url ? this will make the change in all Magento site without modifying the template.

From my searchs I know that images uploaded were added via addImagetoMediaGallery(...) with the file path as one of the parameters. So the idea is to find a way to rewrite (with setdata() maybe) the temp image url and so echo the external url instead of the temp image url.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the `Helper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`. There you could override the functions `getImageFile()` or `setImageFile()`.

Comment: Thank you @David-Lambauer. But I think rewriting the `Helper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` is a heavy manipulation. Is there any simple way to simply override image urls ? May be in the `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` code is it possible to use the new text field attribute instead of the uploader to store the image urls ?

Comment: I do not know a better way. I think your changes will need an editation of the magneto core. May you'll could find a way to hook into an observer but i didnt find an event yet.